# JQuery datatables adding column classes to dynamic content

Tags: c#, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable that has dynamic columns

```html
<table id="dt_basic" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover tableSearch">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.ColumnInfo) {
            <th>@Html.Raw(@item.ColumnHeader) </th>
            }
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I want to set the column type and column class after the datatable is populated

```
    var table = $('#dt_basic').dataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "ajax": "@Url.Action("LoadResultGrid", "Verifications", new { id = Model.RunId })",
        "deferRender": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "scrollX": "100%",
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [1],
                "searchable": true,
                "visible": true
            }
        ]
    });
```

Model.ColumnInfo is a List of objects with attributes: ColumnHeader, ColumnType, ColumnClass.

So I need to loop through the columns after the table has been created and match the column header to Model.ColumnInfo.ColumnHeader and then set the column type to the corresponding Model.ColumnInfo.ColumnType and the column class to the corresponding Model.ColumnInfo.CoulmnClass.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out how to resolve my issue and thought I'll share it in case someone else has a similar issue.

I added razor code to generate javascript that added clasName attribute to columndefs dynamically.

```
    var table = $('#dt_basic').dataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "ajax": "@Url.Action("LoadResultGrid", "Verifications", new { id = Model.RunId })",
        "deferRender": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "scrollX": "100%",
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
            @for(var i = 0; i < (Model.ColumnHeaders.Count); i++){
                if (Model.ColumnHeaders[i].ColumnClass != null)
                {
                    @: {"targets": [@i], "className": "@Model.ColumnHeaders[i].ColumnClass"},
                };
            }
        ]
    });
```

The resolved javascript snippet:

```
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
                     {"targets": [5], "className": "do_rightalign"},
                     {"targets": [6], "className": "do_rightalign"},
                     {"targets": [7], "className": "do_rightalign"},
                     {"targets": [8], "className": "do_rightalign"},
```